# How to export 3D "screenshot" of a model in XNA 3.1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, xna

My program generates a static 3D scene using XNA 3.1.
The scene is created using input parameters, and is different every time.

I need to export the final scene as a 3D object of sorts so our partners can view it locally on their system. They are open to any format, as long as there is a small enough viewer for it (not full suite of 3dMax or Maya!)
They are looking to be able to zoom in and out and rotate the scene.

Is there anything as simple as SaveMesh() in XNA?
What file formats I should use (OBJ? FBX? X?)

VS2008, C#, XNA 3.1

Answer (score 0):

XNA is pretty limited in terms of working with models in-game, as far as I am aware.  After the Content Pipeline imports a model, that's basically what you get.  You can translate, scale and rotate the model to your heart's content, but that's about all.

I think we need more details about the goal of this project.  Is there any reason you can't just compile the program and give it to them, using the game itself as the viewer for your scene?  If exporting the scene to a model file is not necessary (i.e., if this is purely for inspection), then this seems to be the simplest solution.  You could even save states of the particular scenes you want so your partners would not have to re-enter the appropriate input values.

However, if you are trying to compile a model mesh out of different structures and export it to a 3D model file format, XNA is *not* your tool of choice.  It's for making games, not 3D modelling.

If you are set on trying to rig up a way to manipulate models in-game, you might check out [this tutorial on custom model structures to override XNA's Model class](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/custom_model_class), however, I warn you-- I've read through this before and there is no way to export.  Honestly I don't think XNA designers have ever *considered* exporting a scene in model data format (again: game framework, not modelling framework).

Finally, if your structures are simple enough, consider using vertex declarations to stitch together the models procedurally.  I'll warn you-- this is not fun, especially if you don't have experience working directly with primitives on the graphics device.  If you manage to create your structures using vertex and index buffers, you may be able to come up with a way to serialize and save this into a .x or .fbx file format.  At this point you are basically writing your own 3D modelling program.  It will be very difficult.

Comment: I see. I'll keep looking, but if what you're saying is true, can you recommend a way to transform my 3D data (assuming I have all the underlying coordinates and textures) into an exportable file? Free libraries? Maybe .X and .FBX is not the best choice, if all I want is to export.

Comment: I have no experience in that.  You'll have to read up on how the file type is compiled.  I doubt there are any libraries for it.